# node.js SIGINT handler not printing my message

Tags: node.js, console.log

I am implementing a program that can save the "session" of a running process by outputting a JSON object to a file. I want this saving to happen when the user hits Control+C.

I have implemented it as follows:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('\nCaught Control+C. Saving session...');
    filename = 'session_'+randomString(10)+'.saved';

    fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify({
        'jobs': jobs,
        'config': config,
        'verbose': verbose,
        'max_retries': max_retries
    }), function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR while saving session file!');
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('The session file was successfully saved to "' 
            + filename + '"!');
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

I expect the last `console.log` line to output `The session file was successfully saved to session_blabla123.saved!` but the message is not printed. **The file is saved correctly**, this is not the problem. I just want to message to appear on the terminal.

I'm OK with having the program wait for a few seconds before quitting if that will fix the problem. I also tried:

```
console.log('The session file was successfully saved to "'+ filename + '"!');
setTimeout(function() {
    process.exit();
}, 2000);
```

But the program still quits immediately. I've also looked into flushing the console output but there doesn't seem to be any good way to do that (looked at [Is it possible to flush the console (make it print immediately)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306279/is-it-possible-to-flush-the-console-make-it-print-immediately#22306500))... is there any workable solution?

Comment: Are you using Node.js on Windows? As far as I know, `SIGINT` is not always correctly dispatched on Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021373/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-process-onsigint-in-node-js

Comment: No, I'm using it on Mac OS X. The SIGINT handler itself is working fine (the session file is being saved correctly). It's just that the console message isn't being printed... *sometimes* the initial "Saving session..." message is printed, but most of the time, nothing is.